# Single Linkage Clustering with Manhattan metric

Tags: machine-learning, distance, hierarchical-clustering

Say suppose we are having 5 data points with 3 attributes each ...
(4,3,1) (2,1,5) (1,2,3) (2,3,1) ....

Now let us build the distance matrix. If we do Manhattan metric then the cell corresponding to points (4,3,1) and(2,1,5) will give 0 as (4-2)+(3-1)+(1-5)=0 .Same for the cell corresponding to points (1,2,3) (2,3,1).So we should merge (4,3,1) (2,1,5) and (1,2,3) (2,3,1).Let us suppose that our threshold is 0.1.

But I can't understand that how a point whose corresponding attributes are so far from each other like (4,3,1) and (2,1,5) can be merged ??I mean should we really merge them ?????

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the absolute value signs. Manhattan metric is defined as

$$
d(x,y) = \sum_i | x_i - y_i |
$$